# Android BufferUnderflowException

Tags: android

Имеется GL поток. Из этого потока совершается подгрузка некоторых данных (именно из GL потока, не из отдельного). Выглядит это дело так:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements Renderer{
....
private static final Object synch=new Object();
private static boolean load;
....

public static void DataLoad(String name){
    try{
        byte data[];

        InputStream ist=this.getAssets().open(name);

        if(data.length!=ist.read(data)){
            err("DataLoad error");
            ist.close();}

        data=new byte[ist.available()];

        ist.read(data);
        ist.close();

        ByteBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

        x=buf.getFloat();
        y=buf.getFloat();
        z=buf.getFloat();
        ....
    }
}

@Override public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl){
    ....
    synchronized(synch){
        if(!load){
            LoadData("data.bin");
            ....
            load=true;
        }
....
```

Если просто запустить, то все работает отлично, но если параллельно совершать `onTouchEvent` (тыкать или водить по экрану), то программа вылетает с такой ошибкой:

> java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
>   java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:117)
>   java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getFloat(HeapByteBuffer.java:105)
>   com.app.Main.DataLoad(Main.java:1103)

Тут `Main.java:1103` - это строка `x=buf.getFloat()` либо `y=buf.getFloat()` либо `z=buf.getFloat()`. То есть видимо поток обработки ввода как-то влияет на выполнение загрузки.

Может кто знает в чем дело, и как-нибудь решить проблему без выноса загрузки в отдельный поток?